# How to solve Magento 1.7 Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object Message

Tags: magento, object, fatal-error

I'm running accross a situation here.

As far as I know, in previous versions of Magento, if one got this PHP fatal error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\wishlist\view.phtml on line 50
```

You should do a simple change in page.xml file, so that :

```
<block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml"/>
```

would become:

```
<block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/>
```

But now... running Magento 1.7 this solution doesn't seem to work anymore!

Anybody has a solution for that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's on your `wishlist/view.phtml` line 50?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's obvious, that your problem is not related with, the xml layout directive, that you've mentioned:

```
<block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/>
```

The fatal error is fired on line 50 in file app\design\frontend\base\default\template\wishlist\view.phtml

I guess, that you have updated your magento installation recently.

Can you please do the next experiment:

1. In your active theme temporary rename layout/wishlist.xml to layout/wishlist-back.xml
2. Clean up Magento cache
3. Try to reproduce the problem again
4. Share with us the result

Comment: The question about the block tag is correct! Thanks Ceckoslab!

Comment: Hi @GilbertoAlbino is it possible to mark the suggested solution of Drew Hunter as accepted. As I see he just gave better explanation of the problem. For sure his solution is easier to understand by other people.

Answer (score 7):

This is a perfect example of why people should use **local.xml** for base theme layout overrides!

The problem is that when working with your previous verison of Magento, at some point you copied over wishlist.xml from the base theme to your custom theme and not the wishlist template files.

There were some new blocks added to the the wishlist layout between version 1.6 and 1.7.

[Line 50 of wishlist/view.phtml](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/view.phtml#L50) is trying to call toHtml on a child block named `control_buttons`...

```
<?php echo $this->getChild('control_buttons')->toHtml();?>
```

This block was only introduced in 1.7, so the wishlist.xml file you have from a previous version does not declare that block - hence the error " Call to a member function toHtml() on a **non-object**"

So, to resolve this you need to try and merge the 1.7 base wishlist.xml file with your customized verion - essentially adding in the new blocks declared in 1.7.

[1.6 wishlist.xml here](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.6/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/wishlist.xml)

[1.7 wishlist.xml here](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/wishlist.xml)

Comment: This solution worked fine! Thanks Drew. When I grow up in Magento I wanna be just like you man :p hehe